# How can I eliminate all comments going into moderation?

Tags: comments

I've been asked to rescue an authors' blog following a sketchy plugin explosion.  Following their debacle, one of the things that occurred is that all of the comments made by members are being held for moderation & I can't figure out how to fix this.  The settings are properly configured to allow a user with a previously approved comment to post without going into moderation, there are no URL's in the comments held (all comments are being held), but the issue still persists.  Is there a common error with relation to this?

Comment: there's no such thing as posts being held for moderation in standard WordPress, what plugin implements this? Or do you mean comments?

Comment: Aye, let me wipe the egg from my face- I do mean comments.  That's what I get for starting work before my brain does.

Comment: In the admin area, click on Settings and then Discussion. Then, make sure "Comment author must have a previously approved comment" and "Comment must be manually approved" is **unticked**.

Comment: Yes, I did get that right - that's all been done but the comments are still being held for moderation. This is why I've posted this here because it should be working fine but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two scenarios here:

1. The behavior is technically correct, you interpret configuration incorrectly
2. The behavior is technically incorrect, as caused by something

Unfortunately there are a lot of moving part in processing the comment submissions.

The part most relevant to moderation is in [`check_comment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_comment/) function.

It checks:

- if moderation is enabled
- if comment contains excessive number of links
- if comment contains blacklisted words
- if moderation is loosened for known commenters

This involves multiple options and some filters, any of which could be going wrong. Beyond this it's impossible to make a better guess, it will need hands on debug.

Comment: There is another scenario - I was brought into the picture after some bad blood & some of the things I fixed in their theme seemed deliberate.  Still, it leaves us essentially with scene 2.

Comment: I believe I've found the cause - the comments.php was from an entirely separate theme (2012).  Looks like another deliberate action to me, sorry for the confusion.